Help: wedge product on another wedge product
I'm reading P.64 of Ch.6 of Harris' book. Here is an extraction of a particular paragraph there.

We have described the Grassmannian $ G(k, V) $ as a subset of $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda^k V)$; we should now check that it is indeed a subvariety. This amounts to characterizing the subset of totally decomposable vectors $\omega \in \Lambda^k V$, that is, products $\omega = v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$ of linear factors. We begin with a basic observation: given a multivector $\omega \in \Lambda^k V$ and a vector $v \in V$, the vector $v$ will divide $\omega$—that is, $\omega$ will be expressible as $v \wedge \varphi$ for some $\varphi \in \Lambda^{k-1} V$—if and only if the wedge product $\omega \wedge v = 0$. Moreover, a multivector $\omega$ will be totally decomposable if and only if the space of vectors $v$ dividing it is $k$-dimensional. Thus, $[\omega]$ will lie in the Grassmannian if and only if the rank of the map $\varphi(\omega) : V \to \Lambda^{k+1} V$ s.t. $v \mapsto \omega \wedge v$.


I'm new to the exterior algebra and trying to understand what $\varphi(\omega)$ is. My understanding is that $\varphi$ is a $k-1$ vector and $\omega$ is $k$-vector. So,

Isn't this supposed to be a product of these two vectors involving wedge products?
How can I intuitively understand this map? Is this like $\omega$ is acting on an arbitrary input vector from $V$?
At the bottom of P.64, there is a part "$\varphi(\omega)$-the subspace $W$ itself.". Why is it a subspace $W$?

Thanks!

I think I will study Multilinear algebra first... Thanks

The last $\varphi$ (a function) is not the same thing as the firsw $\varphi$ (a multivector). The author just made a poor choice in reusing a variable. The function $\varphi$ is nothing more than what the author states: $v\mapsto\omega\wedge v$. It has little to do with the multivector $\varphi$.

@NicholasTodoroff oh,,,, Thank you so much for the clarification!!
